# How to set a control's position according to another in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a page like this:

```
<Grid>
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       here are contents
       they are forever absolutely in the center of the screen
       no matter of the resolution/size
   </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Everything is working fine. But now I want to add a back button in the top-left corner.
[image: example]

And I don't want to split the grid into 2 columns and 2 rows like this:
[image]

the contents are no longer absolutely centered, even we can split the grid by percent, because the contents are sometimes very wide and sometimes very narrow.

I want to know how can I keep the contents horizontal/vertical aligned "Center", and then set the back button's position relatively to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*slightly hacky ansewer*

You might be able to achieve by positioning your stackpanel in the center, and then set a negative left margin the width of the button to shift everything left by the required amount...

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-45,0,0,0">
        <button with width and padding totalling 45px />
        here are contents
        they are forever absolutely in the center of the screen
        no matter of the resolution/size
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Oh! negative margins! I used this skill in css, I don't know it works in xaml too.. I'll try your solution next week, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a grid layout with 3 columns to ensure the content is centered with the columns widths set to *,Auto, *. This will ensure the main content is always centered and not care about the size of the button. You can then use margins to set the seperation as required. This is a techinique I have used in SL, WPF & Metro.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Do Something"/>
    <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="My custom content"/>
</Grid>
```